Excel Workbook "Save As" .xlsm creates link to Macros in Previous workbook. Can I keep a Macro saved from old workbook self-contained in new workbook?
I am having trouble with the Object model in VBA. I start with a blank Workbook called Test1.xlsm. I Add a New Module to the Workbook Called "TestModule1" In "TestModule1" I write a Sub called TestMacro1. This Sub opens a MsgBox and Displays "Hello Numpty!".
I go into the option to customise the Ribbon, add a Custom Tab and assign the Macro "TestMacro1" to a new button in the Custom Tab.
I then "Save As" "Test2.xlsm". And close the Excel App - which closes the file "Test2.xlsm" and the Excel App itself.
I then go into Finder - I'm on a Mac but I've had the same issue on Windows - locate "Test2.xlsm" and open the File "Test2.xlsm", which opens up a new instance of the Excel App and a copy of "Test2.xlsm". It then asks me to Enable Macros - no issues, this is expected behaviour. I then navigate to the custom tab on the Ribbon, and execute the Macro "TestMacro1" by clicking on the button I added in the Ribbon.
It then gives me the following warning:
"This Workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe."
This is the part I don't understand. There is no data in the Workbook, and I expected the Module to be a module within the new Workbook.
I suspect it's because Module sits above Workbook in the hierarchy and adding it to the Ribbon is at the Application level, so the ribbon - by default - references the original Module in the Workbook "Test1.xlsm".
I'm not in a desperate hurry to do version control for a simple Macro. And "Save As" seems a logical way to do this. But, I would like to keep my code "self-contained" in the one file.
Can anyone explain to me how I can do this? And, what I am missing about the object model?
Thanks in advance...
Mike
I've searched all over the web and in stackoverflow. I've written loads of VBA, and this part of the Object model and Ribbon is the part I can't understand. And, I can't seem to be able to do something that seems relatively straightforward - or a straightforward workaround.
Maybe the Module is self-contained to the .xlsm, but adding a button to the Ribbon locks it to the Test1.xlsm file, and I need to dynamically repoint the ribbon button to a new file in a VBA "save as" function? Or, I'll have to kick off a macro that generates buttons in a worksheet by using a "Create buttons" Sub, but I can't kick this off from the Ribbon because it'll still go to the old file, and I'll have to use the Visual Basic -> "Macros" -> Run "Create Button" macro? Seems "limited" if so...

The custom ribbon setup needs to be included in the file itself - if you add it via the "customize the ribbon" in the UI then as you guessed it just points to the original file.  See links here for example: https://web.archive.org/web/20200819232814/https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm   If you just want to keep backup copies then you can use SaveCopyAs to save a date+timestamped version whenever you want a "Checkpoint" to go back to.

Thanks @Tim-Williams, I have done that in the past, but I wasn't overly keen on using old - no longer maintained - tools. But, at least I know what my options are. I'm just going to run the macro from the drop-downs, and I'll create buttons etc. dynamically. It's an odd choice by Microsoft to not allow an option to keep it all in the same file - especially when it's clear that it's possible. But, as they're focusing on OfficeScript - pants for my needs, I don't think that'll change now. I would have marked as the answer but seems to be no option for that as just a reply. Thanks again!
